# Resize image on Android Splash screen using layer-list

Tags: android

How can I resize the screen to have it more centred on the page

**initial_screen.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:opacity="opaque">


     <item
         android:drawable="@android:color/white"/>
     <item>

         <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/fsa2"/>
    </item>


</layer-list>
```

[image: Splash Screen]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an ImageView and set your drawable resource to it like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_margin="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/fsa2"
         />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: sorry but how you're gonna use that layout code inside the drawable file?

Comment: @FernandoTorres I didn't use layout inside drawable file. I used layout instead of that drawable.

Comment: do you mean using it as windowBackground like <item name="android:windowBackground">@layout/splashscreen</item> ?

Comment: I'm looking for a way to do this explicitly using a Layer-List drawable xml so that it can be set in the Theme with <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/my_layer_list</item> because the theme is loaded and displayed significantly sooner in the startup process than the activity's Layout